# how to uninstall iTerm2 on macOS

Tags: macos, iterm2

If you used HomeBrew to install iTerm2, then simply reverse installation using the revised updated terminal command:

```
brew uninstall --cask iterm2
```

**Note: Running `brew cask uninstall iterm2` causes `Error: Unknown command`**

Comment: Try `brew cask zap iterm2`